# Observables and events issue in angular 2

Tags: reactjs, angular, rxjs

Can someone please tell me why this won't work?

I'm currently taking a course on angular and the instructor has left us in the dirt with regard to updates since the course was made... I'm on the topic of observables and this is the code that isn't working.

```
import {Component, ElementRef} from 'angular2/core'
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx'

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <input id="search" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" />
    `
})

export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef) {
        var elem = document.querySelector('#search');
        var keyups = Observable.fromEvent(elem, "keyup")
            .map(e => e.target.value)
            .filter(text => text.length >= 3);

        keyups.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
    }
}
```

This will not output anything into console and does not provide any errors whatsoever.

What am I doing wrong here?

****Edit****

After pulling my instructors code and re-running everything I'm convinced it is a versions issue with rxjs. In this version I no longer have to include:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
```

And when I write the following code, it works and outputs to the console as expected.

```
/// <reference path="../typings/tsd.d.ts" />

import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx'

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <input id="search" type="text" class="form-control">
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(){
        var keyups = Observable.fromEvent($("#search"), "keyup")
            .map(e => e.target.value)
            .filter(text => text.length > 3);

            keyups.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
    }
}
```

When I pause the app in the debugger and look at keyups it indeed does have the element.

Also for curiosity sake, here is the html that both myself and the instructor are using.

```
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"></style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/styles.css">
    <style>
        body { padding: 30px; }
    </style>
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js">   </script>
    <script  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>

    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
   <script>
      System.config({
        packages: {        
          app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
        }
      });
      System.import('app/boot')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>

  </head>

  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try putting this in `ngOnInit`. I assume you debugged this in your debugger. When you put a breakpoint on the `var keyups` line, and examine `getElementById('search")`, what do you see?

Comment: A suggestion : it is a bad practice accessing DOM directly from component , perhaps you should write directive with ElementRef to DOM manipulation.

Comment: I don't believe the onload thing is the issue, please see edited post.

Comment: @CodeBuster Appreciate the insight. I understand this, but as this is an angular 2 course, I have merely been following the instructors direction up until this point. I'm sure that is the best practice, but for simplicity sake, I think he's just plopped the code into a Component. Not sure. I'll keep this best practice in mind for sure.

Comment: cool just a suggestion :)

Answer (score 2):

In your code `elem` will equal `null`.

I think you should move your code to `ngAfterViewInit` hook. It as 'on load' for component.

See also

- [Lifecycle Hooks](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html)

**[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/tMMPladxgdsE1tz98W8b?p=preview)**